# Can `git checkout $hash $file` errors if `$file` has uncommited changes?

Tags: git

I’m currently leading the migration from CVS to git at work, and I would like to make it as difficult as possible to make unintentional errors for my coworkers.

If you run `git rebase` and you have uncommitted changes, you get the following error:

```
error: cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: Please commit or stash them.
```

This is very good, because it prevent accidental modifications of your uncommitted changes.

When running `git checkout $commit $file`, if `$file` has uncommitted modifications, is it possible to get a similar error? Ideally, I would like to add such flag in `~/.gitconfig` to make it permanent. And if I really want to erase the uncommitted modifications, I’d like to have to type `--force` or a similar flag.

Comment: I don't think so, no. That is one of the main ways to revert changes to a file, even when it has uncommitted changes. -- Trust your devs. Sure they'll make that mistake, but only once or twice.

Comment: What I dislike about `git checkout $commit $file` is that it has 2 purposes: reverting local changes (and in that case, you *want* to remove uncommitted changes), and importing changes from another branch (and in that case you *don’t* want to remove uncommitted changes unintentionally).

Comment: This is why the new version of git have split the functionaries in `git switch` (change branches and create new ones) and `git restore` (remove things from the staging area and restore files to a former state)

Comment: Yes, I realize that new commands where added since I learned git in ~2015. I’m currently reading the "highlight from git" posts from github.com to learn more on what I missed. But I don’t think that the distinction exist between "undo all changes" (when `$commit` == `HEAD` you want to override changes), and "copy that file from another branch" (in that case, you don’t want to accidentally overwrite uncommitted changes). You use `git restore` in both case, isn’t it?

Comment: What is "undo all changes" if it is not "copy that file from a commit"? (note I said commit not branch, as a branch is only a pointer to a commit, and so is HEAD)

Comment: `git checkout $file` or `git restore $file` means "undo all changes". Whereas `git checkout $commit $file` (likewise for git restore) means "copy the content of the file from another revision into the working tree, not "undo all changes considering that the source of trust is what was done in another revision".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no trivial way to get what you'd like here.  Both this form of `git checkout` *and* the newfangled `git restore` command assume that when you ask Git to overwrite `$file` in your working tree from the version found in `$hash`, you really mean it—even if `$file` already exists in your working tree and differs from the copy in the index and/or in `HEAD`.

What you *can* do is write your own Git command.  Pick a command name that does not yet exist.  (I do not know what to call this command, so I'll pick `xyzzy`, one of the two magic words from [Colossal Cave Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyzzy_(computing)).)  Create an executable program—in any language you like; I usually use shell scripts here—named `git-xyzzy` and place it in your `$PATH`.  Then, when you run `git xyzzy`, Git will run your command.

Your command should:

- take a `$hash` and some set of `$file` arguments (you choose how to do this);
- check that the given `$file` arguments either do not exist in the working tree, or are safely committed; and
- run `git restore` or `git checkout` as appropriate.

That's generally a pretty short script, mostly using `git rev-parse` on hash IDs and `git diff` or `git hash-object` to check whether the file is safely committed.